# jQuery multiply only values that are not hidden

Tags: jquery, multiplication, calc

I am pondering how you would add up all values of inputs with specific names via jQuery if their container Div is set to display block.

Something link `if ($('#product_' + this.alt).css('display','block')) {`

Then it needs to add up `.each` with fetching the input something like this.

```
$('#product_price_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val
```

Any ideas on how I would put all of that together?

Edit:

Obviously I should clarify. Encased in the alt tag of multiple checkboxes and radio buttons is an ID that corresponds to the IDs of hidden containers and fields. Therefore the combination of buttons and checkboxes that are checked determines what hidden areas are visible as seen here.

```
function product_analysis_global() {
$(':checked').each(function(){
    $('#product_' + this.alt).css('display','block');
    $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val(this.value);
    var quantity = $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val();
    var price = $('#product_price_PRI_' + this.alt).val();
    var duration = $('#product_duration_PRI_' + this.alt).val();
    var dives = $('#product_dives_PRI_' + this.alt).val();
    var hire = $('#product_quantity_PRI_' + this.alt).val();

    $('#product_price_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(price * quantity);
    $('#product_duration_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(duration * quantity);
    $('#product_dives_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(dives * quantity);
    $('#product_hire_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val(hire * quantity);

});
```

What I need is a field called 'GT_grand_total' to be the sum of all fields that area `'#product_price_total_PRI_' + this.alt).val()'` only if their panel `'#product_' + this.alt` is visible.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do here.  Why are you using `this.alt`? What are these fields? Could you show your HTML?

Comment: Add up or multiply? What is this in this.alt? Consider yourself lucky that I don't down vote badly phrased questions :)

Comment: The this.alt is merely a way of determining the ID of the required fields as they are all dynamically generated. Inside the alt tag is a unique id that is also generated with PHP that corresponds the the alt tags of the required fields in addition.

Comment: Please post full example at http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your requirement

```
var arr = $("div[id*='product_']").not(":hidden").map(function(){
  return $(this).find("input[id*='product_price_total_PRI_']").val();
}).get(); 



var total = 0;
$.each(arr,function() {
    total += parseInt(this);
});
alert(total);
```

Or for total

```
var total = eval(arr.join('+'));

alert(total);
```

Working example

http://jsfiddle.net/wB5Hh/2/

Answer (score 1):

```
var sum = 0;
$("#specific_name_1, #specific_name_2").not(":hidden").each(function(){
    var i = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    if(i){
        sum += i;
    }
});
$("#grand_total").val(sum);
```

Definition of :hidden selector
http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/

Answer (score 1):

If the non-block displayed items are not visible, you can use the jquery `:visible` selector

```
if ($('#product_' + this.alt).is(":visible")) {...}
```

http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/